# Adding to a document library using FileUpload

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I am having major woes trying to add a file to the document library. I have modified a console app to use a FileUpload control.

The major issue is that the file is not added to the library. Then I cannot set any metadata. I receive the error "The object specified does not belong to a list." at the line SPListItem listItem = file.Item;

It seems that SPFileCollection should be used but I did not find an example of that. I want to stay in the server OM. If this entire block is bad please help.

**This is NOT a sandboxed solution.**

```
    private void UploadDocument()
    {
        if (uplProjectDocument.HasFile)
        {
            //Instantiate a new site collection object
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url))
            {
                SPWeb spWeb = site.OpenWeb();
                //Get the list object inside the subsite
                SPFolder listFolder = spWeb.Lists["Documents"].RootFolder;

                string folderUrl = spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + listFolder.Url;
                string fileUrl = folderUrl + uplProjectDocument.FileName;

                // I want the file from the FileUpload control 
                System.IO.Stream fStream;
                byte[] contents = new byte[uplProjectDocument.PostedFile.InputStream.Length];
                fStream = uplProjectDocument.PostedFile.InputStream;
                fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int) fStream.Length);
                fStream.Close();

                SPFile file = spWeb.Files.Add(fileUrl, contents, true, "My Check In comment", false);

                SPListItem listItem = file.Item;
                listItem["Title"] = uplProjectDocument.FileName + "@ " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                listItem.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written incorrect code.

1) spWeb.Files.Add

2) use using block for SPWeb in above case.

Please go through it you will be able to resolve the issue.

```
using (SPSite site = newSPSite("url"))
  {

using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
               {

SPDocumentLibrary documentLib = web.Lists["YourLibraryName"] as SPDocumentLibrary;

Stream fStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
byte[]  _byteArray = new byte[fStream.Length];
fStream.Read(_byteArray, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
fStream.Close();

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

string _fileUrl = documentLib.RootFolder.Url + "/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

bool IsOverwriteFile = true;
SPFile file = documentLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(_fileUrl, _byteArray, IsOverwriteFile);

SPListItem item = file.Item;
item["Title"] = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
item.Update();
file.Update();

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

      });           
 }

 }
```

Comment: This was a concise answer and I have resolved the issue. Thanks. For the lurkers: be sure to use a Path.GetFileName on PostedFile.FileName.